# Change object [SerializeField] for another with script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object

Is possible to change a object [SerializeField] for another with script? I try but doesn't work good i need to change the music with controlled with slider in the scene. The script to controller:

```
public AudioMixer AudioMixer;
public Slider slider;

public Dropdown resolutionDropdown;

[SerializeField] AudioSource audioSrc;
public float Nvolume = 1f;

Resolution[] resolutions;

public GameObject pauseMenuOptions;
```

Comment: Well that serializedfield is private to the script. But yes you can make a method to update the value. Why what did you try? How did it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with SerializeField. Are you aware what SerializeField do? SerializeField in Unity used for reflecting object value to Unity Editor Inspector. It doesn't affect variable protection level. When you didn't assign any protection accessors (private, public, internal), it is private as default. So only accesible in this class level. If you want to access it from another class, you should just add public accessor.

```
public AudioSource audioSrc;
```

Comment: Well i put a incorrect question, i need to know how change a public AudioSource audioSrc in other script, because i have two musics int the scene and i don't know how change between the two musics if i don't use the inspector.

Comment: Why you have 2 audio source in your 1 scene? You can have 1 audio source and 2 audio clip. When you want to change audio just swap between audio clips. Regarding to how to change audio file from other script; get reference to audio source and audio clips, then when you want to change just **audioSource.clip = clipYouWantToSwap;**.

Comment: You would also call `audioSource.Play();` after assigning a new clip ;)

Comment: I use this:gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = Music;
audioSource.Play();
and work perfectly, thankyou very much for the answer.